# How can I (using Twilio Functions example keyword handler) send a POST request to an external website when a user makes a specific selection?

Tags: twilio

When responding to user messages to a Twilio function, if they send a 6 digit set of numbers I want to send those 6 digits as well as the phone that sent them on to another website via POST request for authentication.

I am pretty new to this type of integration but have only been able to reply to the text message sender instead of sending a request to an external website.

```
/*
   After you have deployed your Function, head to your phone number and configure the inbound SMS handler to this Function
*/
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

    const body = event.Body ? event.Body.toLowerCase() : null;
    switch (body) {
        case 'authcode':
            twiml.message("Authenticate your account phone number to app.machinesaver.io by respond to this number with the 6-digit AuthCode sent  when you signed up for an account at app.machinesaver.io/create-admin-account.");
            break;
        case 'help':
            twiml.message("You can ask me ABOUT, ADDRESS, PHONE, or EMAIL");
            break;
        case 'about':
            twiml.message("---------- is a technology company located in -------, -- USA.");
            break;
        case 'address':
            twiml.message("Our address is: Address");
            break;
        case 'email':
            twiml.message("Sales:  \nService:  \nAccounting:  \n");
            break;
        case 'phone':
            twiml.message("Main: PhoneNumber");
            break;
        default:
            twiml.message("Sorry, I only understand HELP, ABOUT, ADDRESS, PHONE, AUTHCODE and EMAIL");
            break;
    }
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

There are no errors but I'm not sure what I can do next to send a POST request to a non Twilio URL from this function for just one of the responses. I imagine I can use a regular expression to find the case when a 6 digit number is texted but after that I am not sure how to send the POST request and wait for a response from the other website (basically authenticating this user's phone number by the 6 digit authcode).

The Twilio documentation recommends adding the following to do a POST request but I'm not sure where to add this in the handler to properly send the request and receive the response (perhaps after the case? or do I need to declare the variables at the top and put the rest in after the case for an AUTHCODE?):

```
var got = require('got');
var requestPayload = {foo: 'bar'};

got.post('https://your-api.com/endpoint', 
  { body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload), 
    headers: { 
      'accept': 'application/json' 
  }, 
  json: true
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.body)
  callback(null, response.body);

}).catch(function(error) {
  callback(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Twilio functions run on nodejs, so you could use native node modules such as [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) to make a POST request and wait for the response synchronously.
2. You could pass control of the message response outside of the twilio function using [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/redirect) . Using the redirect twiml will require your external function to return valid twiml.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems that I have gone down quite the rabbit hole trying to understand what is actually happening with the suggested callback functions in the second bit of code. I think the async path would be ideal for this solution as I don't want this function getting bogged down when multiple users text their authentication code to the twilio phone number. I am now trying to figure out if I can still use the handler example code but put my own http post request within the exports.handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) are just running Node.js, so you can make HTTP requests with the native HTTP module (as Aaron suggests) or by adding dependencies (like `got`) in the [config section of your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure) and using them.

The important thing about doing asynchronous actions, like making an HTTP request, in a Twilio Function is to call the `callback` function when the action has completed, otherwise the action may get cut off before it completes.

Taking your example and expanding on it, sending an optional HTTP request might look a bit like this:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

    const body = event.Body ? event.Body.toLowerCase() : null;
    switch (body) {
        case 'authcode':
            twiml.message("Authenticate your account phone number to app.machinesaver.io by respond to this number with the 6-digit AuthCode sent  when you signed up for an account at app.machinesaver.io/create-admin-account.");
            break;
        case 'help':
            twiml.message("You can ask me ABOUT, ADDRESS, PHONE, or EMAIL");
            break;
        case 'about':
            twiml.message("---------- is a technology company located in -------, -- USA.");
            break;
        case 'address':
            twiml.message("Our address is: Address");
            break;
        case 'email':
            twiml.message("Sales:  \nService:  \nAccounting:  \n");
            break;
        case 'phone':
            twiml.message("Main: PhoneNumber");
            break;
        default:
            twiml.message("Sorry, I only understand HELP, ABOUT, ADDRESS, PHONE, AUTHCODE and EMAIL");
            break;
    }
    if (// some condition that triggers the HTTP request) {
      got.post(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify({ example: 'parameters' }),
        json: true
      }).then(response => {
        callback(null, twiml);
      }).catch(error => { 
        callback(error);
      });
    } else {
      callback(null, twiml);
    }
};
```

Let me know if that helps at all.